Rails 7: Error when running ActionView render - most likely a cache issue
I am upgrading my app from Rails 5 to 7 and Ruby 2.7 to 3.1
I have a job that generates PDFs from an html template.  The old code ran great with this:
    av            = ActionView::Base.new
    av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths
    av.class_eval { include ApplicationHelper }
      
    html = av.render(template: 'invoices/pdfs/show.html.erb', layout: false, locals: { ticket_images: ticket_images })

Apparently the way ActionView works has changed a lot.  I modified the code to this:
    av = ActionView::Base.with_empty_template_cache.new(ActionView::LookupContext.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths), {}, nil,)

    html = av.render(template: 'invoices/pdfs/show', layout: false, locals: { ticket_images: ticket_images })

The first time I run it, it works fine.  Then the second time through I get this error:
ERROR: Error performing InvoicePdfGeneratorJob (Job ID: 28920544-2460-4543-b854-07f61274e615) from Sidekiq(default) in 38.48ms: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `_app_views_invoices_pdfs_show_html_erb___877247439026622302_41760' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000016170>

      public_send(method, locals, buffer, &block)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^):

This feels like a caching issue, but I cannot figure out how to get around it.
Appreciate your help in advance.

There is a built in way to render outside of the controller https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html

Thats fixed me up.   I changed it to this:
  html = ActionController::Base.render(template: 'invoices/pdfs/show', layout: false, locals: { ticket_images: ticket_images })


changed it to this one line:
      html = ActionController::Base.render(template: 'invoices/pdfs/show', layout: false, locals: { ticket_images: ticket_images })

